What are the various methods that can be used to acheive a leveraged position of an underlying security?
Looking for a comprehensive list of the different ways one can leverage a stock position and the pros/cons of the various methods.
Some basic ways I'm familiar with:
1.Borrow at some fixed rate against other assets.
2.Buy deep in the money calls with a high Delta.
3.Buy the call at the money while selling the put.
What are other perhaps more sophisticated ways of achieving leverage.
Of course I could also buy daily leveraged ETFs but I would like to understand how exactly the managers are acheiving this leverage.
Thank you.

Repo or borrowing cash using your security as collateral. Your 2. Doesn't give you much leverage, your deep itm call will have a high intrinsic Value so will be fairly expensive to start with, better off.going with otm or atm options. What about 1x2s/1x3s, if you don't need unconstrained upside?

@user68819 Wouldn't repo only give an extra 50% or so leverage?

@user68819 Buying calls 33.3% deep in the money instead of buying the actual security will give x3 Leverage. Calls 50% deep in the money would give 2x Leverage. This method isn't cheap but at current rates is still considerably cheaper than borrowing outright.

Leverage for options, frequently called 'lambda' ( sometimes effective gearing or also leverage factor), is usually defined as Delta times Stock price/Option price (Δ*s/p_call) and not simply in terms of moneyness.

@AKdemy Wouldn't the lambda of a call 33.3% deep ITM approach a value of 3? amd 50% ITM a value of 2?

Regarding repo, it really depends on the haircut you can obtain, which is security dependent. Quite sure you can get more than 50% leverage though.

@OlderAmateur as per Akdemys comment, it depends on delta which depends on vol, Time to expiry etc. So it's not just a function of distance to/from strike.

In a high vol environment significantly otm options can have high deltas (or colloquially probabilities of ending up ITM by expiry), therefore implicitly giving you more leverage/exposure for lowish levels of premia

If Futures Contracts are traded on the item of interest then they provide an easy way to achieve leverage (and they are so used by the managers of 2x ETFs).

Generally there are 2 ways to achieve leverage:

In Loan Based Methods, the security being purchased is used as collateral for a loan (subject to a haircut i.e. the loan amount is less than the value of the security). The Margin Loan from a stock broker is an example, or the Repo technique used by bond traders in government bond markets.

In Derivatives based methods a separate market is set up to provide leverage (in both directions) to traders who desire it. The Futures markets (established in 19th century in US and UK, even earlier in Japan) are the main example. A more recent example is TRS (Total Return Swaps). In these cases you do not trade the security itself but a contract based on the security. Both sides will have to provide some cash (aka margin) to enter the contract but this will be less than the full value of the security. Essentially one side agrees to pay a multiple of the price change when the asset goes up and expects to receive the same multiple of the the loss from the other side when the asset goes down. They are like two bettors on a football game, one hopes the DownTeam wins the match and the other the UpTeam. Options are another example of a leveraged derivative, but their complexity/nonlinearity is unnecessary if you just need constant leverage. Daily leveraged ETF's mainly use futures and TRS.



Thanks This was the kind of information I was looking for. I still don't understand why buying Deep ITM options don't campare favorably to repo/TRS methods, especially for longer term trades.  For example 12 month calls of Invesco QQQ 33.3% ITM  trade at about 36.84% of the underlying ETF price, or an extrinsic price of about 3.5%. Since you are essentially borrowing 2/3 of the position that comes out to a yearly rate of only 5.25%, while at the same time you only have exposure to the first 33.3% of downside. Where am I going wrong here?
